# How does "drew 'a' last glass from the barrel" differ from "drew 'the' last glass"?

Tags: meaning, articles

> ...kicked off his boots at the back door, drew himself **a last** glass of beer from the barrel in the scullery, and made his way up to bed, where Mrs. Jones was already snoring. (George Orwell, "[Animal Farm](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks01/0100011.txt)")

I cannot differentiate between these two:

- **a** last
- **the** last

Answer (score 7):

*A last* here means that he drew ***a*** glass of beer, which he intended to be his last for the evening.

*The last* would imply that this was the last glass in the barrel—once he drew it, the barrel was empty.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder what you mean by" which he intended to be his last for the evening."

Comment: @nima - he intended to no longer drink beer that day; to finish that glass and then draw no further glasses. So that glass would be his last for the evening. He planned to drink that glass and then no longer drink beer during that evening.

Comment: More generally, I'd say the intended that the glass he drew would be, "the last glass" by some measure [not necessarily the last of the evening] but it would not be "the last glass from the barrel".

Comment: In my opinion, "drew _one_ last glass" would be a more common way to convey the same meaning as "drew _a_ last glass". E.g., "took one last look" or "enjoyed one last bite".

Answer (score 0):

It's the combination of "**the last**" (as in "one that concludes the series or the sequence") and "**a glass**" (as in "container for liquids made of glass" or "amount of liquid that fits in a container made of glass").

It is also possible that the author alludes that the glass just drawn *might not* be **the** last, but *one of several*, each of which the drinker hopes to make his last.

Comment: Thanks. So, did he try no longer drink but he was not confident if he could resist not drinking any other glass?

Comment: I was talking in general.  If he "made his way up to bed", it's likely that he didn't drink any more beer that night.